# Change background Colour in android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, background

I am trying to let the user change the colour of my app via radio buttons. The user clicks on a  radio button, and a method is called. Now I want to change my 5 xml files background colour to x/y/z. But I don't know how I am supposed to reference the xml files themselves, as they don't have an id.I have the 5 colours in string resources , so when i can reference the xml files, the background colour will be changed for all the files.(The hexadecimal notation of the colours replacing the strings). Can it be done or do I have to go back on the merry go round again??

```
 public void rbbgColourClicked(View view) {
            // Is the button now checked?
            boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

            // Check which radio button was clicked
            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.rbbgcolour_grey:
                    if (checked)
                        // Change to grey
                    break;
                case R.id.rbbgcolour_blue:
                    if (checked)
                        // Change to blue
                    break;


                case R.id.rbbgcolour_white:
                    if (checked)
                        // Change to white
                    break;



            }



  }
```

if I put in

```
   LinearLayout one = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.preferences);
                        one.setBackgroundColor(0xff888888);
```

can't understand why its there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using SharedPreferences. You can store the background color hexadecimal code as a preference. When user clicks a radio button, you have to change the hexadecimal code in SharedPreferences.
It is something like this....

in onCreate of each activity...

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
String hexaColor = sp.getString("hexa", "#000000"); //default color will be #000000
```

Then set this as background color of those activities.

When user clicks a radio button then do this...

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("hexa", "new hexa code");
editor.commit();
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setBackgroundResource()`

### Example:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.id.rbbgcolour_grey);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
ll.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```